# Why is my singleton view composer not working, what am I missing?

Tags: laravel

I have created this view composer in my project. But when I run the site it runs the class multiple times. I am using partial loops to generate some menus ang this is the place where views are called many times. And because I set the view composer ( `view()->composer('*', ViewComposer::class);` ) in every view the class is called more than 200 times. I didn't use view composer and singletons before so I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

This is my provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\Composers\ViewComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', ViewComposer::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(ViewComposer::class);
    }

}
```

and this is my view composer

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Composers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class ViewComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        \Log::debug('view composer runned');
        if( auth()->check() ){
            $permissions = auth()->user()->permissions()
        }

        $view->with( "permissions", $permissions);
    }
}
```

This works so the service provider is registered in config/app.php. But as I said the it runs the sql query and the class many many times. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your class look like?  A singleton only ensures a single instance, not only running once.

Comment: What class do you mean? By instance do you mean the class is insanciated once but can be run multiple times anyway? I am creating some menues by getting (injecting) this classes data. But because i am using this view composer for all views (with *) and because i am doing these loops on blades view basis with (@)foreach and (@)include it runs the sql query on every partial view. What i want is run it only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Devon made me clear that binding with singleton ensures not running the class once but instantiate it only once (but still runnable many times) I decided to move the processing (sql query) part to the __construct and store the result into the class' property. So the process will be made only as the class is instantiated only once and the result remain in the singletoned instance.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Composers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class ViewComposer
{
    public $permissions;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->initPermissions();
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with( "permissions", $permissions);
    }

    public function initPermissions(){
        if( auth()->check() ){
            $this->permissions = auth()->user()->permissions()
        }
    }
}
```

This solved my problem with the multiple sql process over and over again. But now I have a lot of views working. This may not a big problem but I guess the proper way to generate these menus is to make the loops within the view composer instead looping them within the view with @foreach and @include. this way I couldn't have multiple views loaded over and over again. Thank you @Devon for your tip.